# Should I change NSDate data in coredata when timezone has been changed?

Tags: iphone, nsdate

I found this issue accidently.

The thing is that I was coding my app in Newyork, which is ALARM app. and I set alarm in the morning time like am 7:00. and It has been stored in core data.

and now I'm in Korea. Good thing is that NSNotification's time has been changed itself so It is fired in the morning right time 7:00 am. BUT it's shown as 8:00 pm in my alarm app. (but It's fired in the morning, by the way, which is cool!)

It's totally understandable. I understood. because the NSDate is just number, It should be like that.

but It seems like there is only way to solve this problem, That is saving timezone together when user set the time and change NSDate data in coredata if timezone would be changed.

It means I ACTUALLY HAVE TO CHANGE NSDATE DATA IN COREDATA!!

Is there cooler way than this to solve it like NSNotification?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a display issue. You can determine the time zone when you display the time as a string and make the appropriate calculations.

I think the alarm went off because maybe you used a timer or a local notification which is of course unaffected once it is set.

Maybe it is not a bad idea to store the time zone to help with the calculation when displaying the time as a string.